# Can you make animations multithreaded? How to improve animation performance

Tags: wpf, animation

I'm using the FluidKit Cube Animation in my WPF application.

The animation is smooth when the application window is not in full-screen, but when the application is running in full screen (maximised - borderless window with no controls), the animation is not smooth.

I noticed the WPF application is hammering a single thread and only utilising one of the four cores of the CPU, memory utilisatio is low.

I'm wondering if there is any way of making the window multithreaded or just the animations multithreaded so the application can utilise more of the available hardware?

Are there any other ways to improve animations?

Ben

Comment: I dont have animations. but my WPF app has a lot UI work. sometime 1000/s logical events. And I suddenly realised that only 4 CPUs are loaded on my i7-920. It seems hyperthreading is not used in WPF...

Answer (score 2):

I will be **really** excited if someone tells me a UI thread in WPF can leverage multi core CPUs....

Jokes apart, GPU and CPU are different concepts sadly. Will it be controversial if I say **"The hardware acceleration mode for WPF apps utilizes GPU's own hyper threading model instead of multi core CPUs."?**

Although there are ways to improve animations such as animating Adorners using PresentationSource, Transforming Drawings and Geometries than Shapes, CompositionTarget.Rendering event, `BeginStoryBoard.HandoffBehavior="Compose"` etc. You will find all of these discussed in details over the internet.

Interestingly there is an old (very useful post) about multi core systems and their impact on parallel .Net frameworks such as PLINQ and WPF 3.0 etc. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/07562a10-17bd-44d3-975b-99ed02bd05de/

I hope this kicks off some very interesting brain storming from our very able StackOverflow experts....

Expectantly Waiting ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid any effects and see how it works and totally avoid bitmap effects, because they force WPF to use software rendering which is not really good.

Suggest you to check out Performance Profiling Tools from Windows SDK. Good luck ;)

Comment: I've been playing with the Perforator and Visual Profiler but they seem to be a bit hit n miss. I enable features like "Draw Software Rendering with purple tint" and nothing happens, I enable "Show dirty-region update overlay" and I get mad flickering of all sorts of colors. I can see my Framerate is remaining under 60fps (which is apparently good) but as for anything else, it seems inconclusive.

Comment: oh, and I did see a noticable improvement when I removed all Bitmap DropShadows.